# Google drive API (Driver.Builder) authentication issues: NullPointerException Precondition check

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm attempting to access my google drive via the drive API and the service to service protocol provided by google but I can't seem to get a drive builder object.

When I try to build an authenticated drive service object I get a non-descript null pointer. Am I missing an authentication step somewhere when I make the service account? I know I'm getting proper access tokens because I did a workaround with HTTP requests and the google OAuth playground, but the drive builder just won't build.

```
public class GoogleDriveService {

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
  JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/** Client Email */
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL =
  "gdrive-p12@generator-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

/** Path to the Service Account's Private Key file */
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "/gdrive-p12.p12";

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
 * @return an authorized Drive client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
    .build();

  System.out.println(credential);

  return new Drive.Builder(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
    .build();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
  // Build a new authorized API client service.
  Drive service = getDriveService();

  // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
  FileList result = service.files().list()
    .setPageSize(10)
    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
    .execute();
  List<File> files = result.getFiles();
  if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("No files found.");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Files:");
    for (File file : files) {
      System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient$Builder.<init>(AbstractGoogleClient.java:333)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.<init>(AbstractGoogleJsonClient.java:74)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Builder.<init>(Drive.java:7783)
    at com.lumos.xlsx_manager.es.da.services.GoogleDriveService.getDriveService(GoogleDriveService.java:59)
    at com.lumos.xlsx_manager.es.da.services.GoogleDriveService.main(GoogleDriveService.java:66)
```

Comment: Check the source AbstractGoogleClient.java:333 to figure out whats checked against null.. You should set that value to build Drive.

Comment: Try checking this its for Google Analytics but the auth using a service acccount is all you need https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java

Answer (score 1):

I think the error might be here:

```
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
```

You're not setting `HTTP_TRANSPORT` to anything, so it's left as `null`.  I would guess that this is what the Google Drive API is complaining about.

Unlike `JSON_FACTORY` and `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`, you haven't declared it `final` either.  Had you done so you might have got a compiler warning about a `final` field never being initialized.

Comment: The HttpTransport object is uninitialized in google's tutorial as well. Do you have any idea what I might set it to?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by using a NetHttpTransport that is apparently not null.

```
Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null) .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).setApplicationName(applicationName).build();
```